# How to display id on URL after clicked on link in php?

Tags: php, url

I have created a form.The user will submit the form and will get the email with the link. After clicked on the link I have to display Id on URL.Would you help me in this?

```
if (isset($result->num_rows) > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $User_id = $row['User_id'];
      }}

  echo $User_id;// I am able to display id here

    $message = "
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>HTML email</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a href='http://localhost/in/abc.php?user_id='" .$User_id. ">Click here</a>
    </body>
    </html>
    ";
```

I am getting output on URL

```
http://localhost/in/abc.php?user_id=
```

Comment: You are using "$User_id" in the first place that works, but then are using "$User_id**1**" afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix you code for both variable you are using and you are also missing quote `

```
<a href='http://localhost/in/abc.php?user_id='" .$User_id1. ">Click here</a>
```

To

```
<a href='http://localhost/in/abc.php?user_id=" .$User_id."'>Click here</a>
```

It should be,

```
$message = "
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>HTML email</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <a href='http://localhost/in/abc.php?user_id=".$User_id."'>Click here</a>
        </body>
        </html>";
```

Comment: Why are you doing '".$user_ud."'?

Comment: sorry , typo. Quote is required at end of href value.

Comment: @NarendraVerma glad to help please accept it helped.

Answer (score 2):

I'd of just done:

```
echo $User_id;// I am able to display id here

    $message = "
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>HTML email</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <a href='http://localhost/in/abc.php?user_id='$User_id1'>Click here</a>
        </body>
        </html>
        ";
```

You don't need to concat the `?user_id='$User_id1'>`